# Adding column to a table by concatenating values from other columns

Tags: awk, cat, table

I have several `csv` table as follow:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;RES1;RES2
1971;1;1;1206.1;627
1971;1;2;1303.4;654.3
1971;1;3;1248.9;662
1971;1;4;1188.8;666.8
```

From this I would like to create a new column that concatenate the values of the columns MONTH and DAY. Therefore the output should look like that:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;RES1;RES2;MONTHDAY
1971;1;1;1206.1;627;11
1971;1;2;1303.4;654.3;12
1971;1;3;1248.9;662;13
1971;1;4;1188.8;666.8;14
```

Comment: After reading your previous question, this one does make much more sense.  You should close the other one which is pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're happy for the header line to also be merged this is simple `awk`

```
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ $(NF+1)=$2$3 ; print}'
```

Basically we add a new field `$(NF+1)` which consists of `$2$3`, which merges those fields.  With `OFS=';'` the fields are output with `;` separator.